# Not able to use JdbcOperator Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to connect to hive table using JdbcOperator. My code is below :

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.jdbc_operator.JdbcOperator import JdbcOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 3, 24),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag_hive = DAG(dag_id="import_hive",default_args=args, schedule_interval= " 0 * * * *",dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))
hql_query = """USE testdb;
CREATE TABLE airflow-test-table LIKE testtable;"""
hive_task = JdbcOperator(sql = hql_query, task_id="hive_script_task", jdbc_conn_id="hive_conn_default",dag=dag_hive)

hive_task
```

I am getting error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'airflow.operators.jdbc_operator.JdbcOperator';
>   'airflow.operators.jdbc_operator' is not a package

I have cross checked the package in sitepackages folder, its available. Not able to figure out why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Install dependencies for using JDBC operator by running the following command:

```sh
pip install 'apache-airflow[jdbc]'
```

and then import `JdbcOperator` in your DAG file like @mk_sta mentioned and as follows:

```py
from airflow.operators.jdbc_operator import JdbcOperator
```

Comment: Now I am getting new error : AttributeError: type object 'java.sql.Types' has no attribute '__javaclass__'. This error is coming in JayDeBeapi package

Comment: Not sure about that, sorry. That is something JayDebeApi specific

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to import [JdbcOperator()](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/jdbc_operator/index.html?highlight=jdbcoperator#module-airflow.operators.jdbc_operator) module will be the following:

```
from airflow.operators.jdbc_operator import JdbcOperator
```

Keep in mind that `JDBCOperator` also requires dependent `jaydebeapi` Python package that needs to be supplied to the current Airflow environment.